# Quantidade de queries para checar usuário no laravel

Tags: laravel, query, api, laravel-5

Tenho um sistema de *autenticação de usuários*, onde uso a `API sentinel` no `Laravel 5.2`.

Quando faço o `Check_user()` no `middleware` pra ver se o usuário esta logado e se tem acesso a rota, ele faz uma verificação de 5 consultas no banco, entre elas:

- **se o user esta logado**
- **permissão**
- **se está ativo**
- **throttle**, *etc.*

*Ficaria pesado para o sistema fazer essa verificação a cada página recarregada?*

**Observação:** cada `query` está levando: *2ms*

Comment: Creio que nesse caso você deve confiar no desenvolvedor da biblioteca. Creio que se  preocupar demais com a microotimização, gera muita gambarras e loucuras no seu código. É sempre bom recorrer a recursos como caches e afins (O Laravel tem bastante).

Comment: Só para enriquecer a discussão, você deve também estudar o manual das bibliotecas que estiver usando nos seus projetos a nível de conhecimento.